# gnuplot - offset xtics

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot, axis-labels

So I have measurements for `x` in `0,100,500,100,1500,2000,2500` and am plotting `with linespoints`.

The problem now, is that when I

```
set xtics (0,100,500,1000,1500,2000,2500)
```

The `0` and `100` tics overlap.

[image]

Can I somehow offset them s.t. they don't? (E.g. move the `0` tic up, closer to the axis?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot offsets for individual tics.

One hacky way I see is to add some spaces to these two labels:

```
set xtics ("0    " 0, "    100" 100, 500,1000,1500,2000,2500)
```